# Как согласовать по родам страну с окончанием среднего рода со сказуемым, выраженным кратким прилагательным?

Tags: согласование

Например, "Марокко/Лесото известн**о**/**а** тем-то и тем-то". Или можно сказать её только с родовым словом? Например, "страна Марокко" или "королевство Марокко".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Род иноязычных  наименований чаще всего определяется по родовому слову: далекое (княжество) Монако, широкая (река) Лимпопо, Если можно использовать два разных родовых слова, то возможны варианты согласования: независимое (государство) Гаити, независимая (страна) Гаити, далекий (остров) Гаити, прекрасный (город) Брешиа и прекрасная (провинция) Брешиа. В некоторых случаях родовая принадлежность существительного устанавливается традицией, поэтому требуется словарная проверка.

Comment: По поводу независимой Гаити есть сомнения. Один и тот же топоним   может иметь разные родовые названия,  у Гаити их два: королевство/государство и остров.

Comment: А в чем проблема, Вера?

Answer (score 1):

Маро́кко (полное официальное название Короле́вство Маро́кко) — **государство** в Северной Африке.

Правило

Род несклоняемых  имен собственных  определяется **по родовому наименованию** (город, река, остров): солнечный Сухуми, широкая Миссисипи).

Поэтому здесь однозначно средний род, так как родовыми наименованиями являются "государство, королевство".

Comment: А слово "страна" для Марокко родовым не может быть? Почему?

Comment: При наличии родового наименования согласование делается по родовому наименованию для любых имен собственных, например: город Москва основан, Москва основана. При отсутствии родового наименования для несклоняемого имени  собственного устанавливается род по официальным источникам. Можно сказать: прекрасная страна Марокко, но: " вскоре территорию современного Марокко захватили вандалы" -  только средний род (государство)  при пропущенном родовом имени.

Comment: То есть родовое слово "страна" неприменимо из-за своей разговорности? Из-за того, что строго Марокко так назвать нельзя?

Comment: Не совсем так. Если нет родового имени, то мы узнаём, о чем идет речь по роду имени собственного. Марокко был основана - это некорректно, потому что  нельзя сказать "страна была основана".

Comment: А "Марокко известна" почему нельзя? Мне кажется странным так сказать, но всё-таки хочется обоснований.

Comment: Ладно, придется Вам разрешить так говорить в качестве исключения. Например: Мароккко: описание страны (это название статьи). Далее текст: Страна разделена на провинции (вилайи), которые, в свою очередь, состоят из префектур, кругов и коммун". В этом тексте допускается сказать "Марокко разделена на провинции ...", потому что родовое наименование "страна" присутствует в названии  и поэтому подразумевается в тексте. Значит,  нужно учитывать тематику текста и вместо имени собственного   (для проверки) подставлять "страна или государство".

Comment: Не надо *мне* ничего разрешать. :) А так, этот Ваш комментарий расставил все точки над i, спасибо, Вера! Я всё понял.

Comment: Это же шутка, не обижайтесь. Отвечая Вам, учусь по ходу сама.

Comment: Нет, конечно, я не обижаюсь. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Можно употреблять с характеризующим словом. Однако если его материально нет, то его нужно подразумивать, например: ***Марокко (государство) известно тем-то***. Но и тут свои подводные камни: страна и государство частично одно и то же. А если это всё-таки страна, то ведь должна быть буква О.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Только не могу понять последней фразы. Должна быть "о" где?